# How do I download from a text file that has a list with links all in 1 run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I've tried using wget in Python to download links from a txt file.
What should I use to help me do this?

I've using the wget Python module.

```
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
body = soup.body
s = "https://google.com/"

for url in soup.find_all('a'):
  f = open("output.txt", "a")
  print(str(s), file=f, end = '')
  print(url.get('href'), file=f)
  f.close()
```

So far I've only been able to create the text file then use wget.exe in the command prompt. I'd like to be able to do all this in 1 step.

Comment: Do you want to still use the `output.txt` file and `wget`, or completely do it without them?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you have a lot of useless operations, what seems to be the problem? What exactly does not work?

Comment: @PeterWood I'm open to using another method.

Comment: @DYZ The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to download the links I get from the text file with  the python wget.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the third party [**`requests`**](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/) library, just use that:

```
from os.path import basename

with open('output.txt') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url)
        filename = basename(url)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
            output.write(repsonse.content)
```

This code makes many assumptions:

- The end of the url must be a unique name as we use [**`basename`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to create the name of the downloaded file. e.g. `basename('https://i.imgur.com/7ljexwX.gifv')` gives `'7ljexwX.gifv'`
- The content is assumed to be binary not text and we open the output file as `'wb'` meaning `'write binary'`.
- The `response` isn't checked to make sure there were no errors
- If the `content` is large this will be loaded into memory and then written to the output file. This may not be very efficient. There are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests) on this site which address that.
- I also haven't actually tried running this code.